# is there have different between distinct() and reduceByKey() in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i have a RDD type like this: `RDD[((String), SomeDTO)]`

this RDD is come from an union method, and I can be sure that the element value of the same key must be the same, so if i want distinct all element of the rdd, what is the difference between the two methods I use

```
\\first
context.union(Array(rdd1, rdd2)).distinct()
\\second
context.union(Array(rdd1, rdd2)).reduceByKey((_, curr) => curr)
```

i'm beginner of spark, the only different i know is that distinct() running slowly

Answer (score 0):

Referring the source code https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5d45a415f3a29898d92380380cfd82bfc7f579ea/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L449 , distinct also follows the reduceByKey approach so you should be alright. distinct would not be slower than reduceByKey.